# Computer Vision 2.0 PDF to text not working

Tags: azure, pdf, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to parse text from a PDF file using Computer Vision 2.0.  I am following the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text) and have changed the MediaTypeHeaderValue to "application/pdf". I get an error that the content type is not supported. I change it to "multipart/form-data" and get an error in processing. How do I use Computer-Vision to process PDF files?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the error that you are getting when it's changed to "multipart/form-data". Input requirements for computer vision 2.0 OCR:Supported image formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP.
Image file size must be less than 4MB.
Image dimensions must be between 50 x 50 and 4200 x 4200 pixels, and the image cannot be larger than 10 megapixels.

Comment: Azure service that can extract (OCR) text within images & translate it insides documents (pdf, docx) is Azure Cognitive Search. learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/… PDFs with combined image and text. Text in PDFs can be extracted during indexing without the use of enrichment steps, but the addition of image and natural language processing can often produce a better outcome than a standard indexing provides.

Comment: Error message was for multipart/form-data was:
`Response:
{
  "code": "BadArgument",
  "requestId": "08a0d362-ad3c-49c4-8dd6-5c13d3029563",
  "message": "Error processing Http request"
}`

Comment: Thanks Ram-msft for suggesting Azure Cognitive Search. Is there somewhere that compares the two services. It seems like the both are supposed to do the same thing and are made by the same company. I imagine one will be going away in favor of the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin,
You are using the legacy "OCR" API that does not support PDF input. Please use the new OCR technology available as the ["Read" API - see overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text) for processing PDF documents. The version 3.0 is in GA since May. Read supports large images and multi-page and mixed languages documents up to 2000 pages long.
Please see the [Read REST API QuickStart in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-hand-text).

Note that Form Recognizer is great if you want to extract not just text, but layout insights such as tables, check-boxes, and key value pairs from forms, use pre-built models, and build custom models to process your documents. It's now in GA.

Comment: Thank you, Sanjeev. You were right about the version. I apparently got confused somewhere while following the documentation and didn't notice the changeover.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Form Recognizer service for extracting data from the PDF.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/

Comment: This does look like an interesting product and I plan to play with it. Right now it's in public preview and its discounted rate is pretty high. I imagine once it hits GA it's going to be astronomical.